# Stringreader Problems

Tags: path, stringreader

I've got a little problem with StringReader and can't figure out why.

If I use a Projekt.Properties.Ressource everything works fine.

But if I just want to use a specific path it doesn't read the xml.

```
StringReader str= new StringReader("C:/TestFolder/Test.xml");


StringReader str= new StringReader(@"C:/TestFolder/Test.xml");
```

Both ways don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
I just have to use

```
XmlTextReader xReader = new XmlTextReader(@"C:/TestFolder/Test.xml");
```

without any Stringreader.